# Rescale parameter in data augmentation

Tags: keras, cnn, data-augmentation

I'm a little bit lost about the rescale parameter in the `ImageDatagenerator` function.
I know that the rescale argument by itself does not augment my data and that by doing `rescale=1./255` it will convert the pixels in range [0,255] to range [0,1].

Currently, I'm only using random flips(vertical and horizontal) and 90º degrees rotations but I'm pondering whether or not I should add the rescale parameter.

My question is what is the advantage in doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As rightly pointed out by you the `rescale=1./255` will convert the pixels in range [0,255] to range [0,1].

This process is also called Normalizing the input. Scaling every images to the same range [0,1] will make images contributes more evenly to the total loss.

Without scaling, the high pixel range images will have a large say to determine how to update weights. For example, black/white cat image could be higher pixel range than pure black cat image, but it just doesn't mean black/white cat image is more important for training.

Also the neural network has a higher chance of converging as it make the coefficients in range of [0,1] as opposed to [0,255] so helps the model process input faster.